# How to create folders for a structure in Umbraco

Tags: structure, umbraco

I am looking at home to create a structure for an umbraco website. I want my site to be similar to below -

- Default (Home page)

  - Products (Subsite)

    - default
    - ProductA
    - ProductB
  - Departments (Subsite)

    - Default
    - DepartmentA
    - DepartmentB

So the URLs will follow -

```
HomePage www.example.com/default.aspx

Products - www.example.com/Products/Default.aspx
ProductA - www.example.com/Products/ProductA.aspx
ProductB - www.example.com/Products/ProductB.aspx

Departments - www.example.com/Department/Default.aspx
DepartmentA - www.example.com/Department/DepartmentA.aspx
DepartmentB - www.example.com/Department/DepartmentB.aspx
```

Can you let me know how I can achieve this in Umbraco.

Thansk

Comment: you achieve this already by naming the nodes as you mentioned: Default, Products, Departments etc. Umbraco creates routes for each of these nodes by the name you give them in the back office, so the URLs will map exactly as you mentioned in your example below based on the node names in Umbraco you have provided at the top.

Comment: How do I create a node for each? I was looking at another article to try work our how to do it, and created a Doc Type called 'Departments' and allowed as a child node to the root, and created a page under that but the URLs seem to be based at the root i.e. www.example.com/home and www.example.com/departments or www.example.com/departmentA is doesnt seem to show the URLs in the properties window in Umbraco '[  /  ]department/' and you can access them using the FQDN appending everything with /home.aspx???

Comment: First node under the root is your Home node. If you name it "Home", you will be able to access it by two URLs: "www.example.com" and "www.example.com/home". Anything created underneath Home node will have the following structure: "www.example.com/<Node name>". And so on, depending on what level of content you have entered: "www.example.com/<node lvl 1>/<node lvl2>.../<node lvlN>

Comment: Take a look at the ~/config/UmbracoSettings.config file - there are options in there to tweak the way urls are generated that may achieve the result you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this, could be to simply create a Document Type named e.g. "Folder". In your Content Tree, you can then simply create one of these "Folders" and name it "Products" and then append children of "Product" to it.